# Backward Stability Lemma

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Lemma-Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with components, $\xi_i$ and $\eta_i$, $1\leq i\leq n$, respectively, that are floating point numbers. Computing the inner product $x^Ty$ on a standard floating point arithmetic machine yields $$fl(x^ty) = (x + \Delta x )^T y = x^t(y + \Delta y)$$ $$\Delta x\in \mathbb{R}^n \ \ \text{and} \ \Delta y\in \mathbb{R}^n$$ $$|\Delta x| \leq \omega_n|x| \ \ \text{and} \ |\Delta y| \leq \omega_n|y|$$ $$\omega_n = \frac{nu}{1 - nu}$$ (inequalities using absolute values of matrices and vectors should be interpreted componentwise.)\ 
You need not prove this lemma but use it to show that the matrix $y = Ax$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ can be computed on a standard floating point arithmetic machine in such a way so as to satisfy $$\hat{y} = (A + \Delta A)x$$ $$|\Delta A|\leq \omega_n|A|$$

Attempted proof: $$fl(Ax) = (A + \Delta A)x = A(x + \Delta x) $$ where $\Delta A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\Delta x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then from the lemma, we see that $$|\Delta A|\leq \omega_n|A|$$

I am not sure if this is what needs to be shown, any suggestions or hints is greatly appreciated. This is a recommended exercise. I posted it to Computational Science but I think it may be a better match here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = [a_{ij}]$ and let $i$ denote any row index, then
\begin{equation}
(Ax)_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j.
\end{equation}
By the lemma there exists $\delta_{ij}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\text{fl}((Ax)_i)) = \sum_{j=1}^n (a_{ij} + \delta_{ij}) x_j, \quad |\delta_{ij}| \leq \omega_n |a_{ij}|.
\end{equation}
Now let $\Delta A$ be given by $(\Delta A)_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$, then
\begin{equation}
\text{fl}(Ax) = (A + \Delta A)x, \quad |\Delta A| \leq \omega_n |A|.
\end{equation}

However, there is not enough flexibility to allow you to write $\text{fl}(Ax) = A(x + \Delta x)$. You can write
\begin{equation}
\text{fl}(r_i\cdot x) = r_i \cdot(x + \Delta x_i)
\end{equation}
for each row $r_i$ of the matrix, but it is *highly* unlikely that the same perturbation of $x$ will work for all $i$.

Comment: I see so given that I correctly applied the lemma to the rows,to complete the problem do I need to do the same to the columns?

Comment: There is the question of writting it nicely, though. I would state that for each row $r_i$ we have a perturbation $\Delta r_i$, such that $\text{fl}(r_i\cdot x) = (r_i + \Delta r_i)\cdot x$ and $|\Delta r_i| \leq \omega_n |r_i|$. Finish by given an explicit formula for $\Delta A$ in terms of $\Delta r_i$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand could you possibly expand upon the answer you provided with what you just stated?

Comment: I have added a some lines which explains what I meant. The important thing is that you think about the matrix vector product as a set of inner products.