# Find the maximum value of a linear system c = A*b (matrix multiplication)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Assuming there is a square matrix A and vector b about to be multiplied.

[A]{b}={c}

However I am interested only in the maximum value within the resulted vector c.
Is there a way to find that without performing normal matrix multiplication and then search in the results?

Comment: Doing a matrix-vector multiplication is (asymptotically) just as slow as simply _reading_ the matrix and the vector (both are $\mathcal O(n^2)$), so unless you have specific restrictions on $A$ and/or $b$ you can't get any asymptotic speed-up.

Comment: I don't follow. If $c$ is known, and you're looking for the maximum value in $c$, you can just look? Or did you exchange the roles of $b$ and $c$ in your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Does the matrix A have any other properties besides it being a square matrix?  real, symmetric, positive definite, sparse, etc.

FWIW, the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector can be calculated using the Power algorithm.  This might provide some useful information.

[Power Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration)

Comment: In fact it has many beautiful properties: real, symmetric , sparse-diagonal(most of entities are gathered near the diagonal), also is should be positive definite to begin with the problem. It might not be positive definite but when that is the case that is where the problem ends. I am aware of that algorithm. How the largest eigen values helps me here?

Comment: Wouldn't the largest eigenvector point in the direction of the maximum response of your linear system?

Comment: Excellent thought, however it does involve for sure larger computational effort than just multiply once and look for the max in C.

Comment: 1. See this other thread.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637931/matrix-vector-product-of-a-banded-matrix

2. Look at Strassen's algorithm.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm

3. Golub & Van Loan, "Matrix Computations," 4th edition, Section 1.4 on Fast Matrix-Vector Products.
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vikash_Pandey5/post/how_to_use_matrix_for_analysis/attachment/59d62ab379197b8077989148/AS:340211683872769@1458124195177/download/Golub_Matrix_Computations.pdf

- Searching the vector c for the largest value can be done in O(n*log(n).